# Why I can't I add dictionaries?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-mining

I have two dictionaries and I want to merge both of them, but it is not working for some reason. This is the code:

```
dict1= {"Player":["Virat Kohli","Jasprit Bumrah","Saurabh Netravalkar"],
    "Role":["Batsman","Bowler", "Bowler"],
    "Team":["India", "India", "USA"]}
dict2 = {"Monank Patel","Batsman","USA"}
dict1.update(dict2)
pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: dict2 is not dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted to do:

```
dict1= {"Player":["Virat Kohli","Jasprit Bumrah","Saurabh Netravalkar"],
    "Role":["Batsman","Bowler", "Bowler"],
    "Team":["India", "India", "USA"]}
dict2 = ["Monank Patel","Batsman","USA"]
dict1['Player'].append("Monank Patel")
dict1['Role'].append("Batsman")
dict1['Team'].append("USA")
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
print(df)

                Player     Role   Team
0          Virat Kohli  Batsman  India
1       Jasprit Bumrah   Bowler  India
2  Saurabh Netravalkar   Bowler    USA
3         Monank Patel  Batsman    USA
```

Edit:

```
dict1= {"Player":["Virat Kohli","Jasprit Bumrah","Saurabh Netravalkar"],
    "Role":["Batsman","Bowler", "Bowler"],
    "Team":["India", "India", "USA"]}
list2 = [["Monank Patel","Batsman","USA"], ["Monank Patel","Batsman","USA"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(list2, columns=df.columns))
print(df)

                Player     Role   Team
0          Virat Kohli  Batsman  India
1       Jasprit Bumrah   Bowler  India
2  Saurabh Netravalkar   Bowler    USA
0         Monank Patel  Batsman    USA
1         Monank Patel  Batsman    USA
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Also, if I had like 70 of those rows, is there an easier way to do that instead of hardcoding?

Comment: You can create a list of lists and append, see edited answer.